# Are there differences between .to_owned(), .clone() and dereferencing (*)?

Tags: rust, clone, dereference, ownership

With this [code on the rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45e01bb4fa41061ba2153f59bd3b94f1):

```
fn main() {
    let a = &[1, 2, 3];
    
    let mut o = a.to_owned();
    let mut c = a.clone();
    let mut d = *a;
    
    o[0] = 7;
    c[0] = 8;
    d[0] = 9;
    
    println!("o: {:?}", o);
    println!("c: {:?}", c);
    println!("d: {:?}", d);
    println!("a: {:?}", a);
}
```

I see:

```
o: [7, 2, 3]
c: [8, 2, 3]
d: [9, 2, 3]
a: [1, 2, 3]
```

All three methods clone the contents of `a`.

Are there any differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a reference to an instance of `Copy` there is no difference.
That is because for `Copy` types:

1. `*ref_to_val` returns a bitwise copy of `val` (and doesn't invalidate old value).
2. The derived `Clone` impl. for `Copy` types will implement `.clone()` using `*`.
3. The blanket `ToOwned` impl. for `Clone` types will implement `.to_owned()` using `.clone()`.

**So it all boils down to bitwise copy.**
This is your case.

If you want to understand how traits `Deref`, `Clone`, `ToOwned` work  for `!Copy` types, you have to understand their purpose and read type-specific docs.
I believe `String` and `str` types are very representative `!Copy` types that will help you understand the magic. Eg. `str` is `ToOwned`, but not `Deref` or `Clone`. Your example won't work for these types.

Comment: Note that _strictly speaking_, the `Clone` implementation isn't automatic and can diverse from bitwise copy. However, doing so is a violation of the API contract of `Clone`, and any behavior (except UB) is allowed for such bogus types.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thank you for your comment. I didn't know how to express it better, not using “automatic” word.   
Do you think “derived” fits better? Theoretically, it doesn't have to be derived. What word would you use?

Comment: Maybe "the semantic of `clone()` on `Copy` types is guaranteed to be equal to a bitwise copy"?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that all relevant traits are implemented sensibly, all three will have the same *result*, and should be equally efficient when compiled with optimization. The differences are in which ones are allowed under what conditions, and what they guarantee. Thus, if you are writing *generic* code (code that works with many different types) it may matter which one you pick, but if the code is not generic, it does not matter other than for readability.

- `*` dereference (without immediately referencing the result) will only compile if the referent of the reference you're dereferencing (the `T` in `&T`) implements the [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait. In that case, it is guaranteed that the result is an exact byte-for-byte copy of the original value the reference pointed to.
- `.clone()`, that is, `Clone::clone()`, will only compile if the type of the referent implements the [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) trait. In that case, it is guaranteed that the result is of the same type as the referent: it goes from `&T` to `T`. There are no compiler-enforced guarantees that the value is identical, but it is *expected* that `Clone` implementations will give you meaningfully “another copy of the same value”, even if its byte representation is different; for example, cloning a `Vec` will give you a `Vec` that has a different heap allocation pointer, but the contents will be a clone of the original vector's contents.

  All types that implement `Copy` must also implement `Clone`, and you can reasonably expect that those types will produce the same result from using either. (That is, if `Clone::clone()` does something different from copying, the implementation is violating [documented expectations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#how-can-i-implement-clone).)
- `.to_owned()`, that is, `ToOwned::to_owned()`, will only compile if the type of the referent implements the [`ToOwned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html) trait. This trait is essentially the same as `Clone`, except that the result type is not required to be the same as the referent type; for example, calling `.to_owned()` on an `&str` will give you a `String`, not a `str` — which is good, because `str` *cannot* be returned by value without some wrapper. This is *why* `ToOwned` exists distinct from `Clone` — to support making clones of dynamically-sized types.

  All types that implement `Clone` automatically implement `ToOwned` [via a blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#impl-ToOwned-for-T). Thus, the only types that implement `ToOwned` in an interesting way are those which *do not* implement `Clone`; these are usually dynamically sized types.

---

To write good Rust code:

- If you can use a dereference, do that.
- If you cannot use a dereference, use `.clone()`.
- If you cannot use `.clone()`, use `.to_owned()`.
- If none of those work, then consult the type's documentation:

  - it may have a specialized operation (e.g. [`File::try_clone()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.try_clone));
  - it may be fundamentally something you can't make a clone of, in which case you may want to share the single instance with `Rc` or `Arc`, or you may need to do something completely different; or
  - the author of the code may have forgotten to provide a `Copy`, `Clone`, or `ToOwned` implementation.